# Vite buildでインポートpathエラーが発生します。

Tags: npm

```
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';
```

Shopifyのこのドキュメントに従って、fly.ioにdeployする時に"npm run build"でエラーが発生しました。
import pathを../nodemodules/から始まるフルパスにしてもダメでした。
どう解決したら良いのでしょうか。

https://shopify.dev/apps/deployment/web

```
#8 9.787 [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "react-big-calendar" from "components/StayCalendar.jsx".
#8 9.787 This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
#8 9.787 If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
#8 9.787 `build.rollupOptions.external`
#8 9.789 error during build:
#8 9.789 Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "react-big-calendar" from "components/StayCalendar.jsx".
#8 9.789 This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
#8 9.789 If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
#8 9.789 `build.rollupOptions.external`
#8 9.789     at onRollupWarning (/app/frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-689425f3.js:41797:19)
#8 9.789     at onwarn (/app/frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-689425f3.js:41613:13)
#8 9.789     at Object.onwarn (/app/frontend/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:23216:13)
#8 9.789     at ModuleLoader.handleResolveId (/app/frontend/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:22466:26)
#8 9.789     at /app/frontend/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:22427:26
#8 9.789     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
------
Error failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd frontend && npm install && npm run build]: exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

この情報だけで理解はよくできませんですが、dependencyの問題かなと思っています。

buildのエラーなので、import pathが大丈夫なら、package.jsonも見せた方がいいと思います。

とりあえず、react-big-calendarはpeerdependencyとしてreactがあるため、package.jsonのdepenciesのところを確認して、reactがなかったら、入れてから、npm install && npm run buildをしてみて。。。

まだ同じエラーが発生したら、詳細をもっと含めた方がいいと思います。